# How to get a tidy excel output of P values from R

Tags: r, excel, export, tidy, r-corrplot

How to get a clean excel dataset of P-values which are exported from R using

```
res <- rcorr(as.matrix(df), type = c("pearson"))
```

I have used the code above to find the P-values across all variables in my data. However, I was interested in exporting these findings into an excel sheet. I have done this by using the following code:

```
write.table(P_val, file="df.csv", sep = ",")
```

The output from this is an excel sheet, however the data is not "tidy" in the sense that all data are in rows, cramped into the same cells, and it is not possible to read the data as there is no sense in how the data are related each variable in this set-up.

What I would like, are tables that indicate the P-value for each variable across all variables.

So what I have done so far is (here I am using simple dataset from R to show what i mean):

```
 df <- USArrests

 res <- rcorr(as.matrix(df), type = c("pearson"))

 P_val <- res$P

 write.table(P_val, file="P_val.csv", sep = ",")
```

I don't really know how to move forward from here, so I hope that someone can help me :-)

Comment: Looks like you just need to reshape `P_val` into your desired format, before you save it as .csv

Comment: Just a note, the output is a CSV file not an "excel sheet".

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `broom::tidy`, and `readr::write_csv` to write it out.

```
library(Hmisc) # for rcorr
library(broom)
library(magrittr) # for pipes %>%
library(readr)

as.matrix(USArrests) %>% 
  rcorr(type = "pearson") %>%
  tidy() %>%
  write_csv("P_val.csv")
```

Result (before `write_csv`):

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  column1  column2  estimate     n  p.value
  <chr>    <chr>       <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
1 Murder   Assault    0.802     50 2.60e-12
2 Murder   UrbanPop   0.0696    50 6.31e- 1
3 Assault  UrbanPop   0.259     50 6.95e- 2
4 Murder   Rape       0.564     50 2.03e- 5
5 Assault  Rape       0.665     50 1.36e- 7
6 UrbanPop Rape       0.411     50 3.00e- 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, when I try this, all data is still cramped in one cell pr. row. Is it possible to spread the data into different cells?

Comment: That is an issue with how you are importing the data into Excel. Nothing to do with this code or its output. I assume you need to specify that the comma is the separator (but I use Excel so rarely I don't recall how).

Comment: Ok, I think I have figured it out now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it works for you.